# SQL Multiple Joins and Where

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

I am having trouble figuring out these errors:

[image]

Comment: did you remove the semi colon after .River? and still an issue? how about the pink lines before Select? maybe it likes to begin at the top most.

Answer (score 2):

Your first join has a semicolon after it, remove it and it will work

Comment: I deleted the stray semicolon and it doesn't work. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: What is your full query now? And what is the new error?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `GROUP BY` clause at very end.

```
 WHERE CONTINENT.NAME='America' GROUP BY GEO_RIVER.RIVER
```